# How would i get the compiler to recognize these characters

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a file and i want to print ou the contents of it but the compiler does not recognize the following:
"/         .   \  ____    \   \    _ -. "
            //"/    /__        -    /__\_\_*\ \"
            "**\  /\   _***   \     .      /_*_*_//**//"
            "**//_*/ \  \   _\  \       -*   __  *"
            "*      _  \  __***/     -  /\    "
            "***    \   -.\    \   **\ /__**/    ."
            "\  \  _\   \   -.      \   **_        "
            "-   \ *_*__**\_\  `__*\***_*\           "
            ".     /*___**//**/    /**//**_**/ "

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  MenuText text;
  string test = "Champion";
  ofstream output("File.txt");
  text.save(output);
  fstream output ("File.txt");
  text.load("File.txt");//This is an error.
  text.print();


MenuText::MenuText()
{
    mText = "Default";

}
MenuText :: MenuText(string text)
{
mText = text;
}
void MenuText::print()
{
cout<< "Story= " << mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
}
void MenuText::save(ofstream& outFile)
{
outFile<<   "/         .   \  \____    \\   \\    _ -. "
            //"/    /__        -    \/\_______\\__\\__\ \"
            "__\  /\   __   \     .      \/_______//__//"
            "__/\/__/ \  \   \_\  \       -   ________  "
            "___    ___  ______  \  \_____/     -  /\    "
            "__    \\   -.\    \\   ___\ \/_____/    ."
            "\  \  \__\   \\   \-.      \\   __\_        "
            "-   \ _\_______\\__\  `\___\\_____\           "
            ".     \/_______//__/    /___//_____/ "<< mText<< endl;
cout<< endl;
outFile<< endl;
}
void MenuText::load(ifstream& inFile)
{
string garbage;
inFile>> garbage >> mText;
}
```

Comment: All literal (single) backslashes '\' in the text have to be written as '\\'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape occurences of `\` as `\\`. Where you want two of them you need to escape both - `\\\\`.

Also note that the second line is commented out:

```
//"/    /__        -    \/\_______\\__\\__\ \"
```

What about:

```
        "/         .   \\  \\____    \\\\   \\\\    _ -. "
        "/    /__        -    \\/\\_______\\\\__\\\\__\\ \\"
        "__\\  /\\   __   \\     .      \\/_______//__//"
        "__/\\/__/ \\  \\   \\_\\  \\       -   ________  "
        "___    ___  ______  \\  \\_____/     -  /\\    "
        "__    \\\\   -.\\    \\\\   ___\\ \\/_____/    ."
        "\\  \\  \\__\\   \\\\   \\-.      \\\\   __\\_        "
        "-   \\ _\\_______\\\\__\\  `\\___\\\\_____\\           "
        ".     \\/_______//__/    /___//_____/ ";
```

Comment: yeah for some reason the second line has an error about missing a close quote :S

Comment: The output just comes out as .  ...... But that got rid of the error.

Comment: Also: when your data looks like this, *don't put it in the source as a string literal* if you can possibly help it. There is no way for somebody looking at this source to judge whether it's what you intended, or whether some extra backslashes crept in somewhere. Better would be to build the string out of smaller parts that aren't gibberish, or to define the gibberish in a text file without escaping and process the text file as part of the build (either as a resource, or write a script to do the string-escaping for you).

Answer (score 1):

`\` is the escape character in a literal string. If you want to represent a backslash you need to apply it twice for each occurance:

```
\ => \\
\\ => \\\\
```

`"` characters inside a literal string also needs to be escaped `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats any `\<any_symbol>` pair as a [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), for example `\n` is a new line, and `\t` is tabulation. Thus every time you use the backslash, the compiler will try to interpret it, and the next symbol as a control character.

To avoid this, you must *escape* each backslash with another backslash, so every time you want to use `\`, you will need to replace it with `\\`. Of course, if you want to use more than one backslash, you will need to escape every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly "does not recognize" means something along the lines of "replaces some characters" or it conplains about illegal escape sequences: the backslash `\` is a prefix for certain special character. You neither need to escape it as `\\` or, with C++ 2011, you could use a raw string. For example, `"\\"` abd `R"(\)"` should both produce a single backslash.